# What would cause AlarmManager to stop

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My app uses an `AlarmManager` to run a `Service` at a specific interval.  Something is causing the `AlarmManager` to stop running, but I'm having a hard time debugging what it could be.  I've heard if an exception is thrown in the `Service` this could cause the `AlarmManager` to stop, but I'm not seeing any exception in `LogCat`.

Any advice on how to debug an `AlarmManager` that auto-stops or what could cause it to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've heard if an exception is thrown in the Service this could cause the AlarmManager to stop, but I'm not seeing any exception in LogCat.

I am not aware that this is the case.

> Any advice on how to debug an AlarmManager that auto-stops

I'd use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to confirm that the alarm really is gone.

> or what could cause it to stop?

The only three things that I know of that will unschedule the alarm are:

- if you do it via `cancel()`
- if the device is rebooted
- if somebody Force Stops your app

Of course, a full uninstall will unschedule your alarms too.

Comment: In the `AndroidManifest` I have the `intent-filter` of `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` for the `BroadcastReceiver`.  Is there anything else I need to restart the alarm if the device is rebooted?

Comment: @KrisB: Well, you actually need some code to reschedule the alarms, in `onReceive()` of that `BroadcastReceiver`. And, you need the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

Comment: I'm confused though, b/c isn't the `BroadcastReceiver` run every time the alarm is run, so wouldn't the alarm be rescheduled over and over, not only on reboot?

Comment: @KrisB: Either use two `BroadcastReceiver`s, or have the `BroadcastReceiver` examine the incoming `Intent`'s action and only schedule alarms when it is the boot event (i.e., not your own broadcast for alarms). See: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled